# C++ 11 How to get enum class value by int value?

Tags: c++11, enums

Can I get enum class variant by my int variable value? Now, I have so enum class:

```
enum class Action: unsigned int {
REQUEST,
RETURN,
ISSUANCE
};
```

And I need get this value from database value (database returns unsigned int). How to optimal make it? Now, just I use switch for each variant, but it's a stupidity. Please, explain me!

Comment: check out `static_cast`. By the way, it's *not*  a good idea to use all uppercase identifiers in C++. They're likely to crash with macro names.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I only start to study C++. Please, write more about it, I don't sure that understand you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can even write a generic convert function that should be able to convert any enum class to its underlying type(C++14):

```
template<typename E>
constexpr auto toUnderlyingType(E e) 
{
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(e);
}
```

With C++11

```
template<typename E>
constexpr auto toUnderlyingType(E e) -> typename td::underlying_type<E>::type 
{
   return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<E>::type>(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's really helpful for me. But how to I can catch error of type casting?

Comment: please, can you explain me what this part of code makes `-> typename td::underlying_type<E>::type`?

Comment: please, explain me how to use this function. Now, I try so: `Action a = toUnderlyingType(my_unsigned_int_var);`

Comment: it's called trailing return type, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: Don't these convert an enumerator (named value) to the appropriate raw integer? I  read OP to want the opposite.  In which case Martin Bonner's answer better addresses the question.

Answer (score 10):

I quite like the switch, because it means you can add a `default: assert(!"Bad value in database");` line.  On the other hand:

```
unsigned int ui = ... ;
auto action = static_cast<Action>(ui);
```

will work too.

Comment: Thank you for sample! I understand that it's a bad way. But I don't have some value else, only from this enumeration.